# SQL query to make a list from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have multiple tables that I want to pull data from to make an item list

Below are the columns I want to capture in my list

item.code, item.description, itemtype.description,  subcategory.description,  UOM.description

The tables and columns are listed below

**Items** table - This is the main source of information
The columns I want to display are
item.code, item.description,

**Itemtype** - Items is linked to item type by Item_type_ID
The column I want to display is 
itemtype.description

**Subcategories** - Items is linked to the subcategories by subcateg_id
The column I want to display is
subcategory.description

**Units of measure** Items is link to the UOM by uom.id
The column I want to display is
uom.description

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been playing with JOINS with varying results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT i.code,
       i.description,
       it.description,
       sc.description,
       um.description
FROM items AS i
INNER JOIN itemtype AS it
    ON i.item_type_id = it.id
INNER JOIN subcategory AS sc
    ON i.subcateg_id = sc.id
INNER JOIN uom AS um
    ON i.uom_id = um.id
```

Comment: Excellent thank you so much. I wish I had found this site sooner

Comment: I have created the query and I am seeing a difference on the number of records returned from a simple query select * from items. On that query I get 4472 records returned. On the answer query I only get 4186

Comment: SELECT i.Item_code,
       i.item_description,
       it.description,
       sc.description,
       um.description
FROM Items AS i 

INNER JOIN item_type AS it
    ON i.itemtype_id = it.id
INNER JOIN subcategory AS sc
    ON i.subcategory_id = sc.id
INNER JOIN unit AS um
    ON i.unitID = um.id

ORDER BY i.Item_code

Comment: @user3029692 Some data might be missing in your 'Items' table. Can you please check if 'Items' table is having proper data in each field?

Comment: Yep found the issue on the item table.